# How to fix Media Exception in Nokia device(J2me)

Tags: java, java-me, media-player, nokia

I am developing a game in J2ME and I am using 4 different sound(midi) files in game.  When I run this game on **nokia** device, it's showing `too many players prefetched` exception.  It's working fine in **Samsung**.  How to resolve this?

Comment: You must accept answer for helping future views of the question. @shalini you have to click on the green tick of the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved implementing a PlayerListener and deallocating sounds after play:

```
  playbackPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(ttsConnection.getFileUrl());
  PlayerListener pl = new PlayerListener() {

      public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) {
          if (event.equalsIgnoreCase(PlayerListener.END_OF_MEDIA)
                  || event.equalsIgnoreCase(PlayerListener.STOPPED)) {
              player.close();
          }

      }
  };
  playbackPlayer.addPlayerListener(pl);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Cause :**

> Many devices have limits of how many sounds can be in the `prefetched` state at once.This differ with devices. On many S60s, for example, it's six ,on many other devices, it is only one.

**Possible Solutions :**

- `Realize` the players, but don't `prefetch` them - they'll be `prefetched` automatically when they play.
- use a `PlayerListener` to deallocate the players after they play, to avoid holding too many in the `prefetched` state.